# Implement Ruby's method_missing inside a JS Class?

Tags: node.js

I need some functionality that works like Ruby's `method missing`. I have searched and only found 2 ways:

1. noSuchMethod: Only available to Mozilla Firefox, and I think it's
   deprecated or something.
2. ES6 proxys: Not yet implemented in Chrome, which is a major browser,
   and partialy implemented in other major ones as per: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/.

I was thinking in proxies but is a major drawback if isn't supported by Chrome, and if it's not supported by chrome, probably not for NodeJS either.

Any idea how to implement this feature? maybe a library or plain JS prototyping?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without a language level feature like proxies or `noSuchMethod`. The prototype chain suffers from the same problem that any other solution does in that there is no generic way of handling calls to missing methods/properties on an object.

Comment: Then as long as proxies aren't implemented in chrome there's no hope to use this kind of feature inside JS?